# Retrieving images from Contentful -Not seeing child image sharp in graphql playground

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful, gatsby-image

I am still new to Gatsby and Graphql and am trying to go through tutorials of using **gatsby-transformer-sharp**, **gatsby-plugin-sharp**, and **gatsby-plugin-image** to retrieve images from Contentful using graphql and map over those images. In all of the tutorials I have read and watched, they have the option of "child image sharp" in their playground and I do not have that.

[This is what graphql looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zyeq9.png)

[This is what my plugins look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hba5Y.png)

Would someone be able to help or walk me through how my query should look and how to map over that data in the query to retrieve those images?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on when are those tutorials done or recorded. Gatsby image has suffered a lot of breaking changes since its creation (see [migration Gatsby 2 to 3](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v2-to-v3/)) changing from `gatsby-image` to `gatsby-plugin-image`.

As you can see in [`gatsby-source-contentful` docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v2-to-v3/) you don't always need `childImageSharp`. It depends on the node you are quyering:

```
{
  allContentfulCaseStudy {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        slug
        title
        subtitle
        body {
          body
        }
        heroImage {
          title
          description
          gatsbyImageData(layout: CONSTRAINED)
          # Further below in this doc you can learn how to use these response images
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Source: `gatsby-source-contentful` docs

As long as your GraphQL contains `gatsbyImage` and `gatsbyImageData` means that the transformers (`gatsby-transformer-sharp`) and sharps (`gatsby-plugin-sharp`) are doing their job.

Your query will rely on your data structure, check the tutorials to understand better, keeping in mind that your data will be under `props.data.allContentfulCarousel` of the page, but it looks that `Images` is an array of images, hence you will need to make another loop through it in order to render the `GatsbyImage` component passing each image.

Comment: I will look into this and follow up if I need more clarification! I appreciate it!